# what's the difference when mapping after a zip operation and mappping after zipped?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I know it's related to the usage of tuples or a bug in Intellij (IntelliJ Community 2018) because it reports both map methods to require f: (Int, String) => B  but when I provide such a function it tells me that I have a compilation failure:

```
List(1, 2, 3).zip(List ("a", "b", "c")).map((a, b) => "blah") //this does not compile 
(List(1, 2, 3), List("a", "b", "c")).zipped.map((a, b) => "blah") //this compiles
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List(1, 2, 3).zip(List ("a", "b", "c"))` creates a `List[(Int, String)]`. When calling `.map` on a `List`, you must pass a function that takes exactly one argument, which in this case is a tuple: `(Int, String)`. You need a `((Int, String)) => B`.

`(List(1, 2, 3), List("a", "b", "c")).zipped` creates a `Tuple2Zipped[Int, List[Int], String, List[String]]`. That class's `.map` method must be provided with a function that takes *two* arguments, the first of which is an `Int` and the second of which is a `String`. You need a `(Int, String) => B`.

`(a, b) => "blah"` is valid syntax for a function taking two arguments, not for one taking a single argument that is a tuple. So it's fine for the latter but not the former.

Comment: so Intellij should report ( in the zip case ) that map needs an f: ((Int, String)) => B not an f : (Int, String) => B, right ?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. It could be that it's dropping some parens or something, but that message is definitely unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, you can try to compile the expressions on some another place (like the [playgrund here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/)).

For your case,

```
List(1, 2, 3).zip(List ("a", "b", "c")).map((a, b) => "blah")
```

should be rewritten as:

```
List(1, 2, 3).zip(List ("a", "b", "c")).map({case(a, b) => "blah"})
```

You should *tuple* the `List(1, 2, 3).zip(List ("a", "b", "c"))` portion be able able to use like `(a, b)`.

For detailed explanation, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22944468/4636715):

Comment: but shouldn't Intellij report map with f : ((Int, String)) => B ?  - please note the double parens